# How to add a str at the end of the while loop

Tags: python

I tried to make a simple guess the number game to learn how to use the while loop. I managed to make the program to tell the user higher or lower the number until they guess the right number.

However I'm trying to add a code that tell the user when the number is right. Like if the guess of the input is == the magic_number (witch is the number to guess) then print Good job you guessed it.

But the program ignores that line of code as soon the input matches the number to guess. I think because the number is right the loop stops and it won't go to the next line of code. But how to I fix this?

```
magic_number=20
guess=int (input("Guess the magic number "))
while  magic_number != guess :
    print("Your stuck")
    if guess >magic_number :
       guess = int (input ("LOWER "))
    elif guess <magic_number :
       guess = int (input ("Higher "))
    elif guess == int (20) : 
       print("Good job, your free")
```

Comment: _"because the number is right the loop stops"_ - yes, that's exactly why! Why not tell them they've escaped the loop _outside the loop_?

Comment: So follow the iterations. Assuming you enter 20, the next iteration will `not` happen and so you will not get the print. That is why you need to put the `print` right after the loop or implement a different looping strategy (i.e. while True or a do-while logic).

Answer (score 3):

Once the new input is grabbed inside of your `if` and `elif` the while loop iterates and checks your while condition which then exits the while loop entirely. In short, it's sort of an order of operations problem that you've run into.

A pretty common pattern is to implement the while to always iterate, and only `break` the loop when a condition is met:

```
magic_number=20
guess=int (input("Guess the magic number "))
while  True :    
    if guess > magic_number :
       print("Your stuck")
       guess = int (input ("LOWER "))
    elif guess <magic_number :
       print("Your stuck")
       guess = int (input ("Higher "))
    elif guess == int (20) : 
       print("Good job, your free")
       break
```

If you are really wanting to use the condition in the `while` to manage the breaking of the loop, then consider moving your input collection to the first step inside the loop. This allows all the branches of your `if/elif/elif` to be viable:

```
magic_number=20
guess=0
while magic_number != guess: 
    guess=int (input("Guess the magic number "))   
    if guess > magic_number :
       print("Lower")
    elif guess <magic_number :
       print("Higher")
    elif guess == int (20) : 
       print("Good job, your free")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of code repetition by using just one *input()* and changing the prompt appropriately as follows:

```
magic_number = 20
prompt = 'Guess the magic number: '
while (guess := int(input(prompt))) != magic_number:
    prompt = "You're stuck\n" + 'Higher: ' if guess < magic_number else 'Lower: '
print("Good job. You're free")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you!

```
magic_number = 20
guess = int(input("Guess the magic number "))

while magic_number != guess:
  print("You're stuck")
    if guess > magic_number:
       guess = int(input("Lower: "))
    elif guess < magic_number:
       guess = int(input("Higher: "))

# When the loop ends, it means the user guessed the correct number
print("Good job, you guessed it!")
```